# Two Packages are using same keyword

Tags: python, package

I tried using 2 Packages and both of them are using same keyword

```
import keyboard
import pynput
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput import keyboard

keyboard = Controller() #From pynput Package

speed = float(input('speed: '))



def start():
while 1 == 1:
keyboard.press('f') #From pynput Package
time.sleep(speed)
keyboard.release('f') #From pynput Package

keyboard.wait('esc') #From keyboard Package

start()
```

The Program Should auto type 'f' and it was working fine but i tried to add "keyboard" package so i can stop the loop but it gave me error

I want hotkey key to stop the loop

error messege :

```
{

"resource": "/C:/Users/ali32/Desktop/Random Files/Python/test.py",

"owner": "python",

"code": "no-member",

"severity": 8,

"message": "Module 'pynput.keyboard' has no 'wait' member",

"source": "pylint",

"startLineNumber": 22,

"startColumn": 5,

"endLineNumber": 22,

"endColumn": 5

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import keyboard as k1
from pynput import keyboard as k2
...
k2.press('f')
k2.release('f')
...
k1.wait('esc')
```